# Use ::: or export everything when developing multiple, related R packages?

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I am working on a family of R packages, all of which share substantial common code which is housed in an internal package, lets call it `myPackageUtilities`. So I have several packages

`myPackage1`, `myPackage2`, etc...

All of these packages depend on every method in `myPackageUtilities`. For a real-world example, please see [statnet on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/statnet/index.html). Each dependent package, of course, has

`Depends: myPackageUtilities`

in its DESCRIPTION file.

**My question is:** In the R code for `myPackage1`, which of the following two techniques for accessing methods from `myPackageUtilities` is preferable:

1. Use `:::` to access the methods in `myPackageUtilities`, or
2. Export everything from `myPackageUtilities` (e.g. by including `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")` in the NAMESPACE)?

Option 2 clutters the end-user's search path, but the [R gurus](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html) recommend against using `:::`.

**Follow-up question:** If (2) is the better choice, is there a way to export everything using roxygen2?

Comment: Can you explain why it's not sufficient to use :: if you're Depend-ing on the package anyway?

Comment: :: only works for exported methods. So, I'd have to export every method in `myPackageUtilities` (in fact by using Depends instead of Imports, you can bypass :: altogether).

Comment: So I guess I'm confused by you saying that you're using Depends. Can't you do what you need by Import-ing the package and exporting all methods? Isn't that what you want anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: Both options **work**, what I'm wondering is which is preferred / better (e.g. taking into account side effects, etc.).

Comment: Oh, well I would almost always prefer Importing a package rather than Depending on one, FWIW.

Comment: I agree with Joran--exporting all of the functions and including the package in `Imports` will actually add no clutter to the search path. Use `Depends` only when you expect the end user to call the functions from the dependency.

Comment: As for adding the exports, I believe you could add the exports in a single file using `@export f g h ....` if you sourced all of the files in the R directory in a clean session, that would give you all of the object names.

Comment: @Benjamin, @joran: Any specific reasons why? I know `Depends` is generally to be avoided, but not sure why this case isn't an exception. I'll happily accept this as an answer if you can explain a bit more below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a package called `randomUtils` and this package has a function called `sd` that calculates the Slytherin Defiance Quotient.

Now I write a package called `spellbound`. If `spellbound` Depends on `randomUtils`, then `randomUtils::sd` will be found in the search path and can conflict with calculating standard deviation.

If `spellbound` Imports `randomUtils`, however, then R will install `randomUtils` but will not load it when `spellbound` is loaded. Thus, the new version of `sd` can't be found on the search path, but can still be accessed by `randomUtils::sd`

With an ever growing body of contributed work on CRAN, it is becoming very important that we use Imports as much as possible so that we don't introduce unexpected behaviors by having conflicting function definitions.

An example of when I have used Depends: when writing the HydeNet package, I wanted the end user to be able to use the rjags package in concert with HydeNet. So I put rjags in Depends so that `library (HydeNet)` would loaf *both* packages. (In other words, put `rjags` on the search path.

Moral of the story, if you don't intend for the user to directly access the functions, it should go in Imports.

Comment: Worth noting explicitly that in all your examples the functions that are expected to be used in any way external the the package *are exported*. (I'm not disagreeing at all with your answer, just being clear since OP talks a lot about exporting in the question and it's not mentioned in this answer). So of course `randomUtils` exports `sd`, but because `spellbound` doesn't DEPEND on `randomUtils`, in the end user's environment `stats::sd` won't be masked unless the end user loads `randomUtils` themself.

Comment: Great explanation! Everything makes sense, but one last thing is bothering me: Why not use `Imports` (as suggested by @Benjamin) but also export _nothing_, using `:::` to access the methods? After all, if the user isn't expected to use the methods then it seems like they shouldn't be exported in the first place.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the source code from `spellbound` could only use functions from `randomUtils` that are exported.

Comment: The triple-colon operator is explicitly designed to allow access to non-exported methods. Also, after this (great!) discussion, I realized that my particular situation is more complicated than I realized at first, so I have opened a new discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118287/best-practices-for-developing-a-suite-of-dependent-r-packages.

Comment: True enough, but keep in mind that if you try to use `:::` in a package, when you run `check`, you'll get the following NOTE: `Unexported object imported by a ':::' call: 'HydeNet:::termName'
  See the note in ?`:::` about the use of this operator.`  The note in the help files states, "It is typically a design mistake to use ::: in your code since the corresponding object has probably been kept internal for a good reason. Consider contacting the package maintainer if you feel the need to access the object for anything but mere inspection."