# Best practices for developing a suite of dependent R packages

Tags: r, dependencies, package, roxygen2

I am starting to work on a family of R packages, all of which share substantial common code which is housed in its own package, lets call it `myPackageUtilities`. So I have several packages

`myPackage1`, `myPackage2`, etc...

All of these packages depend on every method in `myPackageUtilities`. For a real-world example, please see [statnet on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/statnet/index.html). The idea is that a future developer might create `myPackageN`, and instead of having to re-write/duplicate all of the supporting code, this future developer can simply use `mypackageUtilities` to get started.

There are complications:

1) *Some* of the code in `mypackageUtilities` is intended for end-users, and the rest is for internal development purposes. The end-user code needs to be properly documented using roxygen2. This code includes both S3 classes and generics, as well as various helper functions for the user.

2) The dependent packages (`myPackage1`, `myPackage2`, etc.) will likely extend S3 generics defined in `myPackageUtilities`.

**My question is:** What is the best way to assemble all of this? Here are two natural (but non-exhuastive) options:

1. Include `mypackageUtilities` under Imports: for all the dependent packages, and force users to separately load `mypackageUtilities`,
2. Include `mypackageUtilities` under Depends: for all the dependent packages, and be very selective about what is exported from `mypackageUtilities` so as to avoid cluttering the search path. All of the internal (non-exported) code will have to accessed via `:::` in `myPackage1`, etc.

I originally asked a similar question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075215/use-or-export-everything-when-developing-multiple-related-r-packages), but quickly discovered the situation gets complicated quickly. For example:

- If we use Imports: instead of Depends:, then any generics defined in `mypackageUtilities` aren't found by `myPackage1`, etc.

  - This makes using the generic templates provided by `mypackageUtilities` difficult/impossible, and almost defeats the purpose of this entire set-up.
- If I define an S3 generic in `mypackageUtilities` and document it there, how can I have roxygen2 reference these docs in `myPackage1`?

Perhaps I am deeply misunderstanding how namespaces work, in which case this would be a great place to clear up my misunderstanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the rabbit hole.

You may be pleasantly surprised to learn that you can import a function from `myPackageUtilities` into `myPackage1` and then export it from `myPackage1` to make it accessible from the global environment.

So, when you say that you have a function in `myPackageUtilities` that should be accessible by the end user when `myPackage1` is loaded, this is what I would include in my documentation for `fn_name` in `myPackage1`

```
#' @importFrom myPackageUtilities fn_name
#' @export fn_name
```

(See https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/utils.r for an example)

That still leaves the question of how to link to the original documentation.  And I'm afraid I don't have a good answer for that.  My current practice is to, essentially, copy the parameters documentation from the original source and then in my `@details` section write  `please see the documentation for \code{\link[myPackageUtilities]{fn_name}}`

In the end, I still think your best bet is to export everything from `myPackageUtilities` that will ever get used outside of `myPackageUtilities` and do a combination import-export in each package where you want a function from `myPackageUtilities` to be accessible from the global environment.