# R packages that have dependencies like Pkg1 <-> Pkg2 <-> Pkg3

Tags: r, package

I'm not sure if the answer already here somewhere, this is hard to search for...

Consider a series of packages with dependencies `Pkg1` <->  `Pkg2` <-> `Pkg3`.  In words, `Pkg2` contains functions to be used by both `Pkg1` and `Pkg3` (it's a utility package, intended to avoid duplication of the shared code in `Pkg1` and `Pkg3`).  However, `Pkg2` must also import things from `Pkg1` and `Pkg3`.

I'm trying to set this up, and I'm wondering if anyone knows of existing cases of three `R` packages with this structure.  Maybe it's impossible (I've seen errors about cyclic namespace dependencies), or just a bad idea.

The only question I have found that is close is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118850/633251) but it doesn't involve two way dependencies.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: this feels like it might be more appropriate for `r-package-devel@r-project.org` ?

Comment: @BenBolker That's a good idea, if nothing comes up here in the near future I'll do that.  Thanks.

Comment: I think *"the rabbit hole"* is an appropriate reference, as I might imagine a situation where this would seem a plausible solution. In the same breath, though, how certain are you that the three packages are sufficiently orthogonal to be in independent packages? That is, why can they not be two or even just a single package? There are certainly packages out there that are effectively useless without one or more companion packages, but I believe it is generally an exception.

Comment: @r2evans I too liked the rabbit hole reference.  There are definitely two packages in my plans, I'm just trying to figure out whether to use a third package, which is conceptually clean, or stuff all the utility-type functions into one or the other of the two main packages and then users would have to install both to use either.  Having stated that out loud, I guess what I'm asking about also requires two packages to be installed, so maybe there's no gain.